# Homonym function and method. How to call function in the class who contain this method?

Tags: c++

I have an Homonym function and method.

How can I a call function in the class who contain this method ?

I have an error: Circular reference on mkdir() method

```
int FileSystem::Path::mkdir(const std::string &name)
{
    mkdir(name); //This is the c function from sys/stat.h
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: use global namespace explicitly `::mkdir(name);`

Comment: What exactly is causing you problems? What errors do you get? What doesn't work? Can you post a [mcve]? In short; be more explicit and elaborate.

Comment: ::mkdir(name); works perfectly !